# how to plugin WYSIWYG into laravel

Tags: laravel, plugins

Anyone know where is my mistake, i just can't call out the function , can someone point out my mistake ?

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="company_policy_policy_details">Policy Details<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <textarea id="summernote" name="company_policy_policy_details"  class="form-control" cols="139" rows="10" placeholder="Please Enter the Policy Details"></textarea>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#summernote').summernote();
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

i wanna call out the WYSIWYG Editor function into laravel , just i just tried 16 hrs still failed on it.
this is the tutorial i follow from/
link as below : 
https://summernote.org/getting-started/#run-summernote

```
> > <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
> 
> <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) --> <link
> href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
> rel="stylesheet"> <script
> src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> <script
> src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> 
> <!-- include summernote css/js --> <link
> href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote.min.css"
> rel="stylesheet"> <script
> src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
> 
> </html>
> 
> 
> @yield('styles') @extends('master') @section('content')
> 
> 
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-md-12">
>             <br />
>             <h3 aling="center">Create Policy</h3>
>             <br />
>             @if(count($errors) > 0)
>                 <div class="alert alert-danger">
>                     <ul>
>                         @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
>                             <li>{{$error}}</li>
>                         @endforeach
>                     </ul>
>                 </div>
>             @endif
>             @if(\Session::has('success'))
>                 <div class="alert alert-success">
>                     <p>{{ \Session::get('success') }}</p>
>                 </div>
>             @endif
>             @if(Session::has('failed'))
>                 <div class="alert alert-danger">
>                     <p>{{ \Session::get('failed') }}</p>
>                 </div>
>             @endif
> 
>             <form method="post" action="{{route('policy.store')}}">
>                 {{csrf_field()}}
>                 @csrf
> 
>                 <input  type="hidden"
>                         name="policy_category_id"
>                         value="{{ $id ?? ''}}"
>                 />
> 
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <label for="company_policy_policy_category_id">Policy's Category</label>
>                     <select id="bit_app_policy_category_id"  name="policy_category_id" class="form-control">
>                         @foreach($parents as $parent)
>                                 <option value="{{ $parent->id}}" >{{$parent->description}} </option>
>                         @endforeach
>                     </select>
>                 </div>
> 
>                 <div class="<form-group">
>                     <label for="company_policy_policy_title">Policy Title<span class="required">*</span></label>
>                     <input id="company_policy_policy_title" type="text" name="policy_title" class="form-control"
> placeholder="Please Enter the policy title" />
>                 </div>
> 
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <label for="company_policy_version-no">Version-no<span
> class="required">*</span></label>
>                     <input id="company_policy_version_no" type="text" name="version_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the
> Version-no" />
>                 </div>
> 
> 
> 
>                 <form method="post">
>                     <label for="company_policy_policy_details">Policy Details<span class="required">*</span></label>
>                     <textarea id="summernote" name="policy_details"  class="form-control" cols="139" rows="10" placeholder="Please Enter
> the Policy Details"></textarea>
>                 </form>
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <label for="company_policy_expiry_date">Expiry Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
>                     <input id="company_policy_expiry_date" type="datetime-local" name="expiry_date" class="form-control"
> placeholder="Please Enter the Expiry Date time" />
>                 </div>
> 
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <label for="company_policy_file_path">Policy File Path<span class="required">*</span></label>
>                     <input id="company_policy_file_path" type="text" name="file_path" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the
> file path" />
>                 </div>
> 
> 
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <input type="submit"  class="btn btn btn-primary"  />
>                     <a href="{{url('/policy')}}" ><span class="mj btn btn btn-danger">Back</span></a>
>                     <a href="{{url('/')}}" ><span class="mj btn btn btn-danger">Back to home</span></a>
>                 </div>
>             </form>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> 
> <!-- Scripts -->
>     <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
>     <script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.ks') }}"></script>
>     <script>
>         @if(Session::has('success'))
>             toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success')}}")
>         @endif
> 
>         @if(Session::has('info'))
>             toastr.info("{{ Session::get('info') }}")
>         @endif
>     </script>
> 
> > @yield('scripts')
> > 
> > 
> > 
> > 
> > @endsection

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: inspect and check script all are loading correct ? 
show me your full html  code ?
call your script in correct place.. footer of you page and check ??

Comment: remove this form and check `<form method="post">` before text area
and where is the plugin script ? `$('#summernote').summernote();` ??

Comment: There may be have another textarea with id `summernote`. Better option is, add class `summernote` to the textarea, and call it by `$('.summernote').summernote();`

Comment: @Hamelraj i dont know and i just follow the link that i provided

Comment: @hasan05 can u write the code for me ? im totally new to laravel , dun really know how to create the class etc

Comment: Already wrote that. read the previous comment carefully.

Comment: well, change `$('#summernote').summernote();` to `$('.summernote').summernote();`
and on textarea replace `class="form-control"` to `class="form-control summernote"`

Comment: By the way, forgot one thing. check is there any error on console.
If console get any error, then javascript stop execute next codes.

Comment: @hasan05 sorry for disappointing u, i dont even know how to create the class ==

Comment: like how ?   <form method="post">
                    <label for="company_policy_policy_details">Policy Details<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea id="summernote" name="policy_details"  class="form-control" cols="139" rows="10" placeholder="Please Enter the Policy Details"></textarea>
                </form>

Answer (score 0):

Check my repo. It is completely working

https://github.com/senocak/Laravel-CKEDITOR-CKFINDER-usage

Answer (score 0):

> @yield('styles') @extends('master') @section('content')
>       
>           
>               
>               Create Policy
>               
>               @if(count($errors) > 0)
>
>   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
> - {{$error}}
>   @endforeach
>
> @endif
>               @if(\Session::has('success'))
>
> {{ \Session::get('success') }}
>
> @endif
>               @if(Session::has('failed'))
>
> {{ \Session::get('failed') }}
>
> @endif
>
> ```
>         <form method="post" action="{{route('policy.store')}}">
>             {{csrf_field()}}
>             @csrf
>
>             <input  type="hidden"
>                     name="policy_category_id"
>                     value="{{ $id ?? ''}}"
>             />
>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label for="company_policy_policy_category_id">Policy's Category</label>
>                 <select id="bit_app_policy_category_id"  name="policy_category_id" class="form-control">
>                     @foreach($parents as $parent)
>                             <option value="{{ $parent->id}}" >{{$parent->description}} </option>
>                     @endforeach
>                 </select>
>             </div>
>
>             <div class="<form-group">
>                 <label for="company_policy_policy_title">Policy Title<span class="required"> : (Required Field)</span></label>
>                 <input id="company_policy_policy_title" type="text" name="policy_title" class="form-control"
> ```
>
> placeholder="Please Enter the policy title" />
>
> ```
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label for="company_policy_version-no">Version-no<span class="required"> :
> ```
>
> (Required Field)
>
> ```
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label for="company_policy_policy_details">Policy Details<span class="required"> : (Required Field)</span></label>
>                 <textarea name="policy_details" input id="content"  class="form-control" cols="139" rows="10" placeholder="Please Enter
> ```
>
> the Policy Details">
>
> ```
>             <html lang="en">
>             <head>
>                 <meta charset="UTF-8">
>                 <title>Summernote with Bootstrap 4</title>
>                 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
> ```
>
> crossorigin="anonymous">
>
> ```
>                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
> ```
>
> integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
>   crossorigin="anonymous">
>
> ```
>                 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css"
> ```
>
> rel="stylesheet">
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                       $('#content').summernote({
>                           placeholder: 'Please enter the Policy Details',
>                           tabsize: 2,
>                           height: 100
>                       });
>
> ```
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label for="company_policy_expiry_date">Expiry Date<span class="required"> : (Required Field)</span></label>
>                 <input id="company_policy_expiry_date" type="datetime-local" name="expiry_date" class="form-control"
> ```
>
> placeholder="Please Enter the Expiry Date time" />
>
> ```
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label for="company_policy_file_path">Policy File Path<span class="required"> : (Required Field)</span></label>
>                 <input id="company_policy_file_path" type="text" name="file_path" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the
> ```
>
> file path" />
>
> ```
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <input type="submit"  class="btn btn btn-primary"  />
>                 <a href="{{url('/policy')}}" ><span class="mj btn btn btn-danger">Back</span></a>
>                 <a href="{{url('/')}}" ><span class="mj btn btn btn-danger">Back to home</span></a>
>             </div>
>         </form>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> > @if(Session::has('success'))
> >                 toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success')}}")
> >             @endif

```
    @if(Session::has('info'))
        toastr.info("{{ Session::get('info') }}")
    @endif
</script>
```

> @yield('scripts')
>
> @endsection